# Unexpected end of JSON input in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I am creating an app that has CRUD functionalities for localStorage. I am trying to save some data to localStorage via the method `setItem()`, but instead of successfully saving the data, I am getting the following error:

```
Error: Unexpected end of JSON input
```

Here is my Stackblitz URL: https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-efvm9d

To replicate the error:

1. Click on 'Add new product' link
2. Fill in the form and press the 'Add a product' button
3. Observe how the console outputs the error message `Error: Unexpected end of JSON input`

I am expecting to be able to add data to localStorage via the `setItem()` method.

Comment: Please explain why the downvote? I could improve the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the line `localStorage.setItem("rubberboots", rubberboots);` in your code is not correct. `rubberboots` is an Object not a string. You should do:

```
localStorage.setItem("rubberboots", JSON.stringify(rubberboots));
```

BTW, clear your localStorage before trying again, the current value of rubberboots in your localstorage could be null now. It will throw an error when you call JSON.parse() function

Comment: Thanks, but now the function `addRubberboot()` only adds an empty array to the localStorage so that the end result is `[[]]`. Can you tell me what is the issue?

Comment: ah, that is the different issue. I can help you to check it out tomorrow

Comment: Thanks for the offer, but I already got help in another question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54697492/an-empty-array-is-being-pushed-to-localstorage-instead-of-data/54697663#54697663