# An empty array is being pushed to localStorage instead of data

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an Angular application that has CRUD functionalities using localStorage. I need to gather a data object called `rubberboot` from a few input fields and push it to a localStorage key `rubbberboots` which holds an array of objects.

Stackblitz here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-4lgqkx

Using the input fields from **lisaa.component.ts** the data should be

```
{ name: "foo", color: "bar", price: 123, availability: 123 }
```

but instead an empty array is being pushed to localStorage

```
[[]]
```

This piece of code in **kumpparit.service.ts** pushes the `rubberboot` to the localStorage:

```
addRubberboot = (rubberboot: rubberboot) => {
    if (typeof (Storage) != undefined) {
      let rubberboots = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("rubberboots"));
      rubberboot.id = this.generateId();

      rubberboots.push(rubberboot);
      localStorage.setItem("rubberboots", JSON.stringify(rubberboots));
    }
  }
```

and this function generates an `id` for the `rubberboot` object, since the `id` comes from localStorage instead of the input fields:

```
generateId = () => {
    if (typeof (Storage) != undefined) {
      let rubberboots: rubberboot[] = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("rubberboots"));
      let index = 0;
      for (let rubberboot of rubberboots) {
        index++;
      }
      return index;
    }
  }
```

I am expecting the localStorage key `rubberboot` to now hold the value of

```
[ { name: "foo", color: "bar", price: 123, availability: 123, id: 0 } ]
```

and the next push operation to localStorage would set the value of the `rubberboot` key to

```
[ 
    { name: "foo", color: "bar", price: 123, availability: 123, id: 0 },
    { name: "foo", color: "bar", price: 123, availability: 123, id: 1 } 
]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is you define `ruberboot` as an array and assign it an array in your `LisaaComponent` and not an object in your component. The serialization then tries to serialize an array of array.

Change it to this (*I added some initializers, you could change the definition to allow undefined values for the properties if you want*).

```
rubberboot: rubberboot = {availability: 0, color: '', name: '', price: 0, id: 0};
```

Originally you had:

```
rubberboot: rubberboot[] = [];
```

Your updated [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-4lgqkx-9yzb2x)